# Validating file extensions from an array

Tags: javascript

I have searched the Web and SO to figure this one out by myself with many different ways, but with no success.

I would like to show a message if the file extension is accepted or not, in the same fashion as the "outpush.push" statements.

This would need to be taken from an ARRAY of accepted file extensions such as JPG, PNG, GIF and detect if the file extension is uppercase and accept it (convert it to lowercase).

Here is my script. Am wondering how and where in the script could I implement such a feature?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var max_size = 5120; // Max file size

    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        output.push('<li><strong><font size="3" color="FFFFFF">FILE: ', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
            '</font></li>');

        if(f.size > max_size) {

            output.push('<font size="5" color="FFFF00"><b>ERROR!! Sorry, but the file that you selected is too large. Please upload a file that is no larger than ' + max_size + ' KB.');
        }

        if(f.size < max_size) {
            output.push('<font size="5" color="FFFF00"><b>FILE SIZE OK. CLICK TO SEND button below.</font>');

            output.push('<font size="5" color="FFFFFF"><hr><b>IMPORTANT: Do not close this window. Wait till you see the next page when finished uploading your file.</font>');

            document.getElementById("myButton").style.display="all";
        }

    }

    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery?  All of this looks like basic JavaScript.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit my question. I thought it was.

Comment: There are already answers below, but I will add that you have `if(f.size > max_size)` and `if(f.size < max_size)`.  The second should just be an `else` statement.  Also, if `f.size == max_size`, you won't get any message.

Comment: @JeffB - I got rid of one statement and replaced with the other, and still no success. I can't pinpoint where it's failing.

Comment: See my answer below.  It seems to be working in my example.

Comment: Careful, you may be opening yourself up to XSS attacks.  Don't inject user-provided strings into HTML.  Set the innerText of the element instead.

Comment: @Brad Thanks Brad, I'll have a look into that. I'll Google what you said and hopefully I will have this script running without security flaws. Funny you should say that, there was something that did get infected a few months back, but it wasn't injected in the folder the file is presently in.

Comment: @Brad Is there a particular element I should look into?

Comment: @Fred, As a best practice, it is good to look at any place where you are inserting arbitrary data in HTML to convert any reserved characters into the appropriate entity codes.  The easiest way to do this in JavaScript is to manipulate the DOM element properties directly.  The text properties allow you to set the next of an element without worrying about someone injecting HTML (which could contain script tags) into your page.  I don't see anything specific your code that would be a problem, but you do insert arbitrary data into the HTML in several places, where text may be more appropriate.

Comment: @Brad I'm pretty sure that this script is only accessible through a registration form/process, that must first pass through a **"gauntlet"** of validation methods (crypt, sha1, salt) I came up with, but **I do appreciate your input** and will definitely look into it, in order to be sure that injection doesn't happen.

Comment: @mickmackusa I posted this 5 years ago *lol!* - I have no use for it anymore but thanks just the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1) You should use an `if-else`, instead of multiple `if` statements:

```
if (f.size > max_size) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

2) `all` is not a valid value for `display`, use `block` or `inline`:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").style.display = "block";
```

3) You are using outdated `<font>` tags.  Instead, use styles and CSS.  In your case, I would use classes, one for a `msg`, plus additional classes for `error`, `important`, and `ok`.

4) To do the array check, just use `indexOf()`:

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "txt", "png"];  // Globally defined

...

// Get extension and make it lowercase
// This uses a regex replace to remove everything up to 
// and including the last dot
var extension = f.name.replace(/.*\./, '').toLowerCase();

if (extensions.indexOf(extension) < 0) {  // Wasn't found
    output.push('<li class="msg error">ERROR!! Sorry, but the file that you selected is not a valid file type.  Valid types are: ', valid, '</li>');
} else ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/L2Gps/

Answer (score 2):

You can have the array as something like this:

```
var file_types = {'jpg', 'png', 'gif'};
```

and then do something like this in your for-loop

```
if ($.inArray(f.ext, file_types) == -1) {
output.push('<font size="5" color="FFFF00"><b>ERROR!! Incorrect file type! Accepted file types are : jpg, png, gif</b></font>');
}
```

More reading about [inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: The other answers are good for vanilla javascript. I'll keep this answer up for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of two approaches - either try a grab the extension and match it against an array of allowed extensions, or a regular expression.

```
var accepted_types = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png'];
if (accepted_types.indexOf(f.ext) > 0) {
  output.push(...);
}
```

As for the jQuery - you might consider the following for building your HTML

```
var file_list = $("<ul></ul>");
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  // work goes here, simply append the list elements into file_list
  file_list.append($("<li>" ... "</li>"));
}

// to append your new list to id="list"
$("#list").append(file_list);
// or to replace the html with your new html
$("#list").html(file_list.html());
```